# Last Item of RDD not Saved to HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I'm fairly new to Spark and currently doing some basic ETL running on 4 Spark workers, reading items from external sources and then saving them to HDFS. Weirdly I'm missing items in my HDFS result.

Because I need to follow certain file system conventions, I want to split up the items into separate buckets and save them in separate sub-folders (I know I loose performance here):

```
List<String> sources; // some list of strings
JavaRDD<Task> taskList; // a lot of tasks for each source
JavaRDD<Item> items = taskList.map(task -> new Extractor().execute(task));
for (String sourceId : sources) {
  String path = "hdfs:///sources/" + sourceId";
  JavaRDD<String> currentItems = items.filter(
    // filter only matching source ID items
    item -> item.getSource().equals(sourceId)).map(
    // serialise each filtered item
    item -> item.toString());

  // save to hdfs
  currentItems.saveAsTextFile("hdfs:///sources/" + sourceId);
}
jsc.stop(); // done
```

When I debug `.collect().size()` at any time during the transformation/filter/mapping, the expected/correct number of items is displayed. However, when I look through the files in HDFS after the application is done, I only find exactly 1 item per source **less** than expected in the files (I'm aware that Spark writes multiple items into each part-0000x file).

Any ideas? I'm not 100% sure if maybe re-using the same RDD for each `filter(..).map(..)` might be the issue. When I dumped all items in the same folder (without this `for` shenanigan) everything worked as expected. All items were written. I tried `items.cache()` with the current solution, but that wouldn't help either.

I did remove the `.filter(..)` operation and tested with a small data set of 2 sources extracting 6 items each. The result was 12 items in each folder, so the `filter(..`) operation clearly is the culprit.

**Update**: after looking more into the input sources, reducing the amount of sources to easier debug it and find out if the problem only occurs if more items than workers are processed. Some tiny detail of the code might have changed, but after some slight refactoring and testing with increasing data sets, I could no longer observe the issues. Problem solved (hopefully forever). If I ever find out why, I update here.

I'm running Spark 1.6.0 on Hadoop 2.7.2 with Yarn and my Spark application is written in Java8. The application runs smoothly and finishes successful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have less sources  ids in your list `List<String> sources` that you use to filter, than they are in your `taskList`.

If you run `taskList.map(item -> item.getSource()).distinct().count()` will it be equal to `sources.size()`?

If the answer is no, use `taskList.map(item -> item.getSource()).distinct().collectAsMap()` instead of `sources` in your for loop.

Comment: The list of `sources` is generated while the `taskList` is compiled. The size matches. I tested it with a smaller data set and some debugging output, 2 sources, extracting 6 items each, I end up with 5 items in each source folder in HDFS after the operation finishes. I don't think it is a logic error. Must be something special about RDDs and the way they're handled that I don't know yet. If I remove the for loop and just save all items in one folder, I get 12 items as expected.

Comment: Then I have another question. Is your source id invariant to how many times the task is executed?

Comment: Yes. I played around a bit with filter on/off and smaller datasets, suspecting that maybe if I extract less items than workers, all is well and the issue only occurs if I have more items than workers. I steadily increased the items and observed the results. I'm not sure if I should be happy or concerned to report that now even with more data, I get the correct results... devils work -.-

Comment: Anyway. Was a good idea to have a closer look at the sources. Thanks for your help. If I ever find out why this was happening, I update.